# "RNCWebView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am very badly struck in react-native-webview linking. Where I have ended up in this particular issue which is again very common issue.

When i do `react-native link react-native-webview`, it gives me error saying -

warn:: Calling react-native unlink [packageName] is deprecated in favor of autolinking. It will be removed in the next major release.
Autolinking documentation: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md

Hence I followed this link (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md#2-link-native-dependencies) to manually link this package. But still I end up in the same issue from last 2 days.

verions :
**"react-native": "~0.63.4"**,
**"react-native-webview": "^11.2.3"**,

I also see that, for the react-native version above 0.60 we do not have to link explicitly. It does automatically. So I do not know what is the issue in my case.

[image: Webview error]

Can you please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Have you tried to run npx react-native run-android for android --OR-- pod install && npx react-native run-ios for ios platform ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was really helpful. I was just running react-native start every time without running  'npx react-native run-android for android' . The issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a common error when a user adds a new dependency in the project and does not rebuild the project**.

**The dependency with the native code needs to rebuild the project.
Thus here, we have to rebuild the project**.

Have a try with the below solutions:

**For Android**

- in terminal
- npx react-native run-android

--OR--

**For iOS**

- in terminal
- pod install
- npx react-native run-ios
  platform